# Azure log analytics, memory result not showing

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, log-analysis

I wanted to get the performance report of my azure VMs using log analytics. I found a blog [here](https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/calculating-total-memory-and-total-disk-space-in-log-analytics/)

which shows what I wanted.

The problem is when I run the code in my log analytics, it gives all the details except FreeMemoryGB and TotalMemoryGB as shown in the screenshot in the blog. It just shows blank space.

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to [Is there any API to query an Azure VM for free disk/memory space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501252/is-there-any-api-to-query-an-azure-vm-for-free-disk-memory-space), [Azure Free Space metric does not show any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164853/azure-free-space-metric-does-not-show-any-data?rq=1) and [some of Azure virtual machine custom performance counters are not being collected in log analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338997/some-of-azure-virtual-machine-custom-performance-counters-are-not-being-collecte?rq=1)

Comment: Its has to do something with used memory. when i ran this query it gave me nothing:
let UsedMemory = Perf
| where TimeGenerated > now(-60min) and (ObjectName == "Memory" and CounterName == "Committed Bytes")
| summarize UsedMemory = (avg(CounterValue)) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer, InstanceName
| sort by TimeGenerated, Computer desc;
UsedMemory

Comment: For Windows "% Committed Bytes In Use" is the closest which can give you the current memory in use for any windows VM.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59262644

Comment: Ok, What about Total memory of the VM. Is there any counter or way to query that.

Comment: `CounterName == "% Free Space"` `InstanceName == "_Total"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541011/15969115

Comment: Not the disk but RAM memroy.

Comment: You can refer to [Physical memory or RAM usage in Percentage](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/physical-memory-or-ram-usage-in-percentage/m-p/762664),  [RAM usage alert by log analytics | Azure](https://superuser.com/questions/1531228/ram-usage-alert-by-log-analytics-azure) and [How to Monitor RAM Size](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/how-to-monitoring-ram-size/m-p/2091470)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11839577/arun) and [KrishnaG-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10809602/krishnag-msft). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

"% Used Memory" is a counter available for Linux boxes only. For Windows **"% Committed Bytes In Use**" is the closest which can give the current memory in use for any windows VM.

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30m)
| where  CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use" 
| project TimeGenerated, CounterName, CounterValue, Computer
| summarize UsedMemory = avg(CounterValue) by CounterName, bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), Computer
| where UsedMemory > 20 
| render timechart
```

If your Azure VM is Windows OS then query to find disk total free space is:

```
Perf
| where ( ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" )
| where ( CounterName == "% Free Space" )
| where ( InstanceName == "_Total" )
| summarize AggregatedValue= avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 30s)
```

You can refer to [Read Windows VM RAM Memory Log Analytics Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59262644/15969115) and [Is there any API to query an Azure VM for free disk/memory space?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541011/15969115)

Comment: What I want is how much memory has been used which I got but also how much memory it has in total in GB. So that I can compare.

Comment: [Log Analytics Metrics/Counter for Memory & CPU Load](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/log-analytics-metrics-counter-for-memory-amp-cpu-load/m-p/1420896) and [Collect Windows and Linux performance data sources with Log Analytics agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters)

Comment: ok, I see there is no counter for getting total RAM.

Comment: [How to find total size of each disk attached to Azure Linux Virtual Machine from Azure Log analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69026917)

Comment: I think log analytics does not provide VM configs like how much RAM, CPU, Disk config name has been assigned to any VM.

Comment: [Using Azure Log Analytics Workspaces to collect Custom Logs from your VM](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-azure-log-analytics-workspaces-to-collect-custom-logs-from-your-vm-99ef7816a0fe)